# C# Winform : Deployment Problem after using DataRepeater of MS Visual Basics power pack

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service pack 1 comes with Visual Basic Powerpacks which has the DataRepeater control.

I used this control in my c# winform application. in my system everything is running fine. now i copied the debug folder to other system which has only .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed. in this system is giving me error cannot load dependency Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll even i set the Copy Local to "true" for "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" and "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll"

please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

on this page is the information you are looking for: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/12/29/visual-basic-powerpacks-is-released-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2.aspx][1]

i have had some bad experiences with the "Visual Basic Powerpacks" so if possible I woud try to avoid using it.

best regards